# Using Pivot in SQL Server to Display dates as days of the week

Tags: sql-server, datetime, pivot

I have table that has a column of type `DateTime,` I would like to pivot on the datetime column so that the dates are displayed as columns (as days of the week Monday, Tuesday etc).

So for example I have a table like this (can't remember how SQL Server displays full datetimes but you get the idea):

```
BugNo | DateOpened | TimeSpent

1234  | 16/08/2010 | 1.0 
4321  | 16/08/2010 | 3.5 
9876  | 17/08/2010 | 1.5 
6789  | 18/08/2010 | 7.0 
6789  | 19/08/2010 | 6.5 
6789  | 20/08/2010 | 2.5
```

I would like to pivot on the `DateOpened` column to create a result set like this

```
|TimeSpentOnBugByDay|  Mon  |  Tue  | Wed | Thu  | Fri | Sat | Sun
1234                    1
4321                    3.5
9876                           1.5
6789                                   7.0
6789                                         6.5
6789                                                2.5
```

I should point out that I'll only be retrieving one week at a time.

I'm not sure if this is possible, though I'm pretty certain I have seen something like this before (that I didn't write).

Comment: Why not look at the other questions tagged with "sql-server" and "pivot"?

Comment: Hi, I did try that, but couldn't find this specifically nor could I derive what I needed from other examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this

```
SELECT BugNo, [Monday], [Tuesday], [Wednesday], [Thursday], [Friday], [Saturday], [Sunday]
FROM (
    SELECT BugNo, DATENAME(dw, DateOpened) AS DayWeek, TimeSpent
    FROM Bugs
    ) AS src
    pivot (
        SUM(TimeSpent) FOR DayWeek IN ([Monday], [Tuesday], [Wednesday], [Thursday], [Friday], [Saturday], [Sunday])
    ) AS pvt
```