# Pivoting Dates to Day of week

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I'm currently trying to create a grid showing worked hours of employees.

Here's what my data look like (simplified) :

```
|ID    |Client |Task  |Hours  |Date      |
------------------------------------------
|1     |ABC    |A     |3      |09/06/2014|
|2     |ABC    |A     |5      |09/06/2014|
|3     |DEF    |B     |8      |10/06/2014|
|4     |DEF    |C     |8      |11/06/2014|
|5     |ABC    |A     |8      |12/06/2014|
```

And here's what the output must look like:

```
|Client |Task |Sun |Mon |Tue |Wed |Thu |Fri |Sat |
--------------------------------------------------
|ABC    |A    |    |3   |    |    |8   |    |    |
|ABC    |A    |    |5   |    |    |    |    |    |
|DEF    |B    |    |    |8   |    |    |    |    |
|DEF    |C    |    |    |    |8   |    |    |    |
```

My problem is really close to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526604/using-pivot-in-sql-server-to-display-dates-as-days-of-the-week). However there's a major diffrence: it's possible in my case to have multiple values for the same combination of Client-Task-Date.

As shown in the desired output, employees will sometime seperate their work hours even if they worked for the same client and on the same task and i can't use aggregate since all the data shown in the grid will be interactive to the end user.

Is there a way to obtain such output using pivot or any other SQL mechanics such as CASE WHEN ?

Comment: You'll need to use `row_number()` in the subquery and partition by client, date to return rows for multiple dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH t AS (
  SELECT
    Client,
    Task,
    Hours,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Client,Task,Date ORDER BY Date) rn,
    DATEPART(dw,date) DayOfWeek
  FROM MyTable
)
SELECT Client, Task, [1] Sun, [2] Mon, [3] Tues, [4] Wed, [5] Thu, [6] Fri, [7] Sat
FROM t
PIVOT(SUM(Hours) FOR DayOfWeek IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7])) p
```

Comment: Why the messy substring? Why not just `LEFT(DATENAME(WEEKDAY, date),3)`? If on SQL Server 2012 you could also consider `FORMAT(date,'ddd')` but [CLR isn't free](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/trim-time). Also I recommend staying away from shorthand, it saves you 4 microseconds of typing once, [but can cause problems later](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx).

Comment: @Aaron Because it eliminates a dependency on the server's or account's locale.  Ideally, language should be handled entirely client-side, but the SUBSTRING method is a lesser evil than DATENAME.

Comment: What if they *want* to use the locale instead of being forced to English? If that's your justification then you should include that description in your answer instead of just dumping code with no supporting information whatsoever. FWIW, you can also force English with a simple `SET LANGUAGE` command. I still think this substring solution - while mildly clever - is sloppy and unintuitive.

Comment: Day abbreviations are *not* LEFT(DATENAME(WEEKDAY, date),3) across all languages.  SQL Server does *not* store day abbreviations in the locale tables, only the full names.  You can't rely on SET LANGUAGE to solve the problem.  Besides, you're nitpicking something way out of the scope of the original question.